# CreateView and ModelForm with multiple models

Tags: python, django, models

I'm trying to expand the use of the official Django tutorial for practice purposes and to get more accustomed with Django since I'm new to it.

The Django tutorial builds a polling app, in which only the Admin can add polls. I'm trying to expand that and allow registered users to be able to create polls too. For the users I'm using the built-in user model.

My poll models are:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    question_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    activation_date = models.DateTimeField('Activation Date', null=True)
    expiration_date = models.DateTimeField('Expiration Date', null=True)
    public_key = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    hash = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.question_text

    def was_published_recently(self):
        now = timezone.now()
        return now - datetime.timedelta(days=1) <= self.pub_date <= now
    was_published_recently.admin_order_field = 'pub_date'
    was_published_recently.boolean = True
    was_published_recently.short_description = 'Published recently?'


class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    choice_text = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.choice_text


class EligibleVoters(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class PollKeyPart(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    encrypted_keypart = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    decrypted_keypart = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)


class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PollVotes(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Voter(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class PollVotes(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

What I want is to display a form where the user can provide:

- Poll Tittle (question_text in Poll model)
- Active/Inactive Flag or Activation/Expiration Date (all fields in Poll model)
- Multiple Poll Choices (choice_text in Choice model), the user decides how many
- Eligible Voters List (a list of already registered users that the poll creator invites to his poll) (EligibleVoters model)

At the moment I'm trying to find a way to make it work without the Eligible Voters List, but any help or complete solution is welcome.

My forms.py:

```
class PollForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Poll
        fields = ['question_text', 'is_active', 'activation_date', 'expiration_date']


class ChoiceForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['choice_text']


class EligibleVotersForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = EligibleVoters
        fields = ['user']
```

My view.py:

```
def addpoll(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        pform = PollForm(request.POST, instance=Poll())
        cforms = [ChoiceForm(request.POST, prefix=str(x), instance=Choice()) for x in range(0, 3)]
        if pform.is_valid() and all([cf.is_valid() for cf in cforms]):
            new_poll = pform.save()
            for cf in cforms:
                new_choice = cf.save(commit=False)
                new_choice.poll = new_poll
                new_choice.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/polls/newpoll/')
    else:
        pform = PollForm(instance=Poll())
        cforms = [ChoiceForm(prefix=str(x), instance=Choice()) for x in range(0, 3)]
    return render(request, 'voting/newpoll.html', {'poll_form': pform, 'choice_forms': cforms})
```

My urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
    # ex: /polls/
    path('', views.IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    # ex: /polls/5/
    path('<int:pk>/', views.DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    # ex: /polls/5/results/
    path('<int:pk>/results/', views.ResultsView.as_view(), name='results'),
    # ex: /polls/5/vote/
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
    path('newpoll/', views.addpoll, name='newpoll'),
]
```

I don't provide the template file since it doesn't work and I'm unsure on how to display to forms with a single submit button.
I also suspect that my EligibleVoters model is wrong and I have to add some more fields but again I'm not sure abut that either.

Any kind of help or direction is welcome.

Again I'm trying to expand on the official Django tutorial for practice and to make a more usable app. Also I'm testing some stuff with private/public keys(thus all the keys in my models) for practice purposes and this might also end up as a small project for a class at my uni.

Answer (score 0):

You can put multiple form tags in one form HTML element

```
<form action="." method="post">
    {{form-one}}
    {{form-two}}
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

then in your view:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form-one = FormOne(request.POST)
    form-two = FormTwo(request.POST)
    if form-one.is_valid() or form-two.is_valid():
        ...
```

Comment: Unfortunately I already tried this and it doesn't work. The forms don't show up event though the res of my HTML file is rendered correctly. Maybe there is a mistake somewhere in my view.py?

Comment: instead of the list comprehension loop try setting the forms explicitly or using formsets

Comment: Can you provide some code on how to do that? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: check out the documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates